# Create table from based excel data does not working anymore - Azure Logic Apps

Tags: excel, excel-formula, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I am trying to create Logic App which will get me specific excel file from SharePoint document library and transform data into table in this excel.

Based on several blogs and videos -
[createTable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fwAoCKFdn4&ab_channel=MichaelAlex),
[Create Table with logic apps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5wxLrD8BZc&ab_channel=PragmaticWorks)

Using this formula `=OFFSET(Sheet2!A1,0,0,SUBTOTAL(103,Sheet2!$A:$A),3)` in Table range does not working anymore. I could not find any topics about this.
Any suggestions ?

[image: TableLogic]
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my expected results:

Firstly, I have below File in SharePoint and and its values in Excel are:

[image]

The **`Design`** which worked for me with using your Formula is :

[image]

Formula means the table range in Sheet 2 that begins at cell A1, and it has a height which matches the number of valued cells in column A of Sheet 2, and has a width of three columns.( as i have given 3 columns in input).

**`Output:`**

[image]

The problem is not with Logic apps, power automate, The formula is also correct, you have to give correct formula to work it out according to your input.